# Why is my RAID-1 disk inactive?

Tags: linux, raid-1

The state of my RAID-1 disk (created with two SATA Disk Drives) is "inactive" and I don't know why. It should be active under normal circumstances.

I just want to know in which case would a RAID-1 disk state become inactive.

Would a faulty SATA disk of RAID members cause the inactive state? Or a disk with no-fresh data? How can I fix this?

Comment: You should mention the hardware or software you are using for RAID, such as mdadm softraid or a specific hardware controller.

Answer (score 3):

This means that the RAID device has not been assembled.  It does not imply the disks are faulty.  Its possible/probable that /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf does not exist, and the raid device was not assembled at startup.

Try activating the disks with

```
mdadm -A /dev/mdX
```

If that fails, try reassemblig it by running the following as root:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/mdX
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/mdX /dev/sdX /dev/sdY
```

To make the change permanant run

```
mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```